# A simple wsgi website with python, but the .css file does not load. Why?

Tags: python, css, styles, wsgi

Why is my background not blue when I go to `localhost:8080` in my browser?
The following 3 files are all located in the same directory:

wsgiwebsite.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

cont = (open('wsgiwebsite_content.html').read())

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return [cont]

server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, application)
server.serve_forever()
```

wsgiwebsite_content.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wsgiwebsite_style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    This is my first web page
  </body>
</html>
```

wsgiwebsite_style.css

```
body{background-color:blue;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSGI only serves your Python code and probably doesn't even know about existence of that CSS file.

You can either configure your web-server to handle static assets for you, or use something like [static](http://lukearno.com/projects/static/) to also serve static media.

Comment: When you say "configure your web server", do you mean configure the `wsgiwebsite.py`-file? How do I do that? Thanks for the static alternative, but I'd like to do it without resorting to external libraries.

Comment: Typically WSGI application is not exposed to the internet- some ordinary Web server is in front of it (Apache, nginx, lighttpd, etc). You can configure Web server to serve your Python app at URL "/", and configure "/media/" URL to point to directory that contains static files.

Answer (score 1):

You try to load the css via your wsgi server but your server always just returns the html file. Have a look with firebug/web inspector/... to see the response from the server for the css file.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet below is just for learning purpose. I created a static directory and saved my index.html and css file there, thus my own source code files are not accessible.

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server                                    
import os                                                                        


def content_type(path):                                                          
if path.endswith(".css"):                                                    
    return "text/css"                                                        
else:                                                                        
    return "text/html"                                                       


def app(environ, start_response):                                                
    path_info = environ["PATH_INFO"]                                             
    resource = path_info.split("/")[1]                                           

    headers = []                                                                 
    headers.append(("Content-Type", content_type(resource)))                     

    if not resource:                                                             
        resource = "index.html"                                                  

    resp_file = os.path.join("static", resource)                                 

    try:                                                                         
        with open(resp_file, "r") as f:                                          
            resp_file = f.read()                                                 
    except Exception:                                                            
        start_response("404 Not Found", headers)                                 
        return ["404 Not Found"]                                                 

    start_response("200 OK", headers)                                            
    return [resp_file]                                                           

s = make_server("0.0.0.0", 8080, app)                                            
s.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Denis code almost SOLVED the problem for ME, but I needed to make some changes/fixes, and this is what I got working:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from cgi import parse_qs, escape

import codecs                                                                       
                                                                             
                                                                             
def tipoDeConteudo(path):
    if path.endswith(".css"):
        return "text/css"
    else:
        return "text/html"                                                       
                                                                             
                                                                             
def web_app(environment, response):                                                
    caminho = environment["PATH_INFO"]
    resource = caminho.split("/")[1]

    headers = []
    headers.append(("Content-Type", tipoDeConteudo(resource)))                   
                                                                             
    try:
        resp_file = codecs.open("indexResposta.html", 'r').read()
    except Exception:
        response("404 Not Found", headers)
        return ["404 Not Found"]                                                 
                                                                             
    response('200 OK', headers)
    return [resp_file.encode()]                                                        
                                                                             
s = make_server("0.0.0.0", 8080, app)                                            
s.serve_forever()
```